# Whatsapp Business appears in the list as an option to activate Deep Sleep but standard Whatsapp does not appear

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, samsung-one-ui, android-14, samsung-galaxy-s-23

One UI 6
Samsung Galaxy S23

As Whatsapp consumes a lot of battery, I'm trying to put it in Deep Sleep to only work when I open it. But only the Whatsapp Business version is appearing in the list of apps as an option to activate the functionality.

Should I do something so that Whatsapp appears in the list and I can choose it?

Comment: Maybe a Samsung thing. On Pixel, I can put ordinary WhatsApp in optimize mode. I don't have business version